# Android Displaying Snackbar Inside Fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I am running into some issues with displaying a snackbar inside a fragment. I can set one up fine for an activity but when I try in a fragment it just doesnt appear and no error is given.

**Snackbar inside fragment**

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "Snackbar test", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
View sbView = snackbar.getView();
TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
snackbar.show();
```

**rootView in fragment**

```
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_possible_recipes, container, false);
```

**Fragments XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/no_result"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/filterButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_filter"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/floatingButton" />


 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Main Activity XML**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout2">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.example.rory.pocketchef.Fragments.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: @ JJSmith i please check my code

Comment: I think you have to pass object of FloatingActionButton in Snackbar.make() not rootview.

Comment: I tried the floating action button but same issue still

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**try this way**

```
  rootlayout = (CoordinatorLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
```

and Snackbar

```
  Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootlayout , "Snackbar test", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                            TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                            textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                            snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 25):

You can get it done far easily just by using it like following.

```
Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content),
           "text to show", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This should work in anywhere within a Fragment.

PS. I know this is old but I leave it here anyway for future reference.

Comment: Works like a charm, simple and elegant way to do it

Answer (score 1):

```
Snackbar.make(requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout),"your message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
.show();
```

android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".YourFragment">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem just like yours. The way i got the snackbar to appear was by adding the code below to the onCreateView method of the fragment in question:

```
Snackbar.make(rootView,"Snack bar!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
```

Remember to make sure the layout of the fragment in question is a Coordinator Layout.

Answer (score -1):

In fragment you can put Snackbar this way, by putting container

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(container, "I am Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.show();
```